# Copying <article> URL to onclick for whole article div with jQuery

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have a list of articles as such:

```
<article>
  <a class="title" href="http://somelink1.com">Some Link</a>
  <p>content</p>
</article>

<article>
  <a class="title" href="http://somelink2.com">Some Link</a>
  <p>content</p>
</article>

<article>
  <a class="title" href="http://somelink3.com">Some Link</a>
  <p>content</p>
</article>
```

I'm trying to grab the `href` attribute and copy it over to each `<article>` as an `onClick`.

I have this jQuery that almost works, but it's only using the first article URL for every other one.

```
$("article").each(function() {
  var copyLink = $("a.title").attr("href");
  $(this).click(function() {
    window.location = copyLink;
  });
});
```

Help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to navigate to the .title tag for each of the article. `.find(".title")`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("article").each(function() {
    var copyLink = $(this).find(".title").attr("href");
    
    $(this).click(function() {
      window.location = copyLink;
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article>
  <a class="title" href="http://somelink1.com">Some Link</a>
  <p>content</p>
</article>

<article>
  <a class="title" href="http://somelink2.com">Some Link</a>
  <p>content</p>
</article>

<article>
  <a class="title" href="http://somelink3.com">Some Link</a>
  <p>content</p>
</article>
```

Answer (score 1):

To make jQuery no longer take only the first href, you need to make it search in the current item of the $.each

```
var copyLink = $(this).find("a.title").attr("href");
```

To make your script work you can do something like this:

```
$("article").each(function() { $(this).click(function() { window.location =  $(this).find("a.title").attr("href"); }); });
```

I apologize for any typos. I wrote the answer from my phone.

Comment: thank you, yes, this is what I was missing. I accepted the other answer because it's what I tried first, but I'm sure your answer works just as well. thank you.

Comment: No worries. Glad we were able to help :)